# Good way of clamping things to a mic stand

Tags: microphone, field-recording, microphone-stand

I'm starting to think about audio recordings that I want to make in the next few months and one of the sounds I'd like to capture is rain on an umbrella.

My first thought was that I could stand holding an umbrella over my recording gear but I have problems with patience and would probably only last a minute or two before I wanted to move - This would cause noise from the raincoat that I would undoubtably be wearing and throw off the point of the recording in the first place.

My next thought was to clamp the umbrella onto a stand which was also holding the recorder and mics. This seems like a good idea but I'm missing a few parts of the picture to evaluate it properly.

Given an average mic stand set at its lowest (about 1m-1.2m) and that I'm likely to be recording on uneven ground (a country park), what can I use to clamp the umbrella to the stand and still be able to set an angle for it? and how can I reduce the chance of the whole thing blowing over?

Comment: When it comes to clamping, manfrotto is a great resource https://www.manfrotto.com/us-en/products/stands-arms-and-clamps/

Comment: I had a look through the Manfrotto site (UK version for me) but couldn't find anything that really did the job. I guess I was hoping for something more like the clamps you used to get in school science labs: a very short rod with a claw/clamp at either end. ...I think I may have just answered my own question. I'm off to look for school science supplies!

Comment: MIght try one of these: https://www.rapidonline.com/Eisco-Retort-Clamp-3-Prong-with-Bosshead-52-3305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cheap way of doing this.

I went online and found a scientific equipment supplier and ordered a few "Retort Clamps" (picture below) for a few pounds each - very cheap and will fasten almost anything to a mic stand at any angle.

I think these will do the job and potentially many more around the studio.

[image: Scientific Retort Clamp]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a lighting umbrella, straight into a light stand - made for each other.

Random picture from Google…

[image]

The lighting clamps generally come with adaptors &/or inserts so they'll fit a mic stand thread [either size], or otherwise they'll just drop right over the end of a standard  mic stand & clamp to the straight rod underneath.

**…or… gaffa tape.**

Comment: Thanks, THat's certainly something to think about although a little expensive for a single recording - I'd have to find more uses for the umbrella afterwards to justify it a little more ;)

Comment: Just go with the gaffa tape then …so long as you're not using the same mic stand your mic is on, otherwise I think it's going to be a tad rumbly ;)

Comment: I'm going to be using a suspension holder so I'm not too worried about rumble - Gaffer tape may well end up being the solution - I was just hoping there was something just a touch more elegant out there

Comment: You don't really need elegant, you just need somerthing that will hald an umbrella up for half an hour. You'd get far better isolation using two mic stands, though ;)